# Is there a CCK fieldtype that would display a static field?

Tags: entities

I'm looking for something like the 'textfield' CCK fieldtype, except instead of displaying a label and an edit box with a value - it would just display a label and a value as text during both edit and view operations.

So for example, as a textfield it might display like this:
label: [value]

as a 'static' CCK fieldtype it would display like this:
label: value

I've tried disabling a textfield, but our User Experince folks don't like the fact that the field has a box, but yet really never becomes editable.

Thanks for all your help,
Greg

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you don't need an input element at all. In this scenario, you can use `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` in a custom module of site specific customizations to add a form element of type 'item':

```
$form['my_form_component'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#title' => t('My Label'),
  '#markup' => t('This text follows the label'),
  '#description' => t('An optional description appearing below the markup'),
);
```

See the [Forms API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#item) for more details.

Edit: If you're not interested in custom modifications, the [Markup module](http://drupal.org/project/markup) seems to provide this kind of utility in a contributed module for D6